# Redirect single subdomain url to root domain url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am looking to 301 redirect a single url on a subdomain to a url on the root domain. Eg:

'sub.domain.com/page' to redirect to
'domain.com/work/name'

I do not want to affect any other pages on the subdomain, the subdomain should operate as normal, aside from that one specific url.

How would this be achieved the .htaccess?

Thanks in advance.
Darrell

Answer (score 0):

Using mod_rewrite, you can put these rules in the htaccess file in your subdomain's document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/page$ http://domain.com/work/name [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looking at it again I have realised the subdomain url I need to direct has an additional directory in it -

"sub.domain.com/folder/page"

How can I add this into the rules you have supplied?

Thanks again.

Comment: The .htaccess isn't working  - I am assuming that is because there is a CNAME record on the subdomain with a url value of 'externalsub.externaldomain.com'

Comment: I have updated my question with more clear information here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954555/redirect-a-subdomain-url-that-has-a-cname