# Redirect a subdomain url that has a CNAME

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cname

I am looking to 301 redirect a single url on a subdomain to a url on the root domain. Eg:

'sub.domain.com/page' to redirect to 'domain.com/work/name'

I do not want to affect any other pages on the subdomain, the subdomain should operate as normal, aside from that one specific url.

The subdomain also has a CNAME record with the value 'shopname.bigcartel.com'

I tried the .htaccess suggested in my [previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906035/redirect-single-subdomain-url-to-root-domain-url), but that was before I knew there was also a CNAME record active.

How can I achieve the redirection?

Thanks in advance. Darrell

Answer (score 0):

Add such strings to .htaccess in root of sub.domain.com, not in root of domain.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page$ http://domain.com/work/name [L,R=301]
```

Must work

Comment: It is not working. I have added those rules to the .htaccess in the root of the subdomain, but it has to effect. What could be causing the .htaccess to be ignored? The CNAME record?

Comment: Does sub domain work? have you added this line at the top of .htaccess - before other redirections?

Comment: Yes, the subdomain works. Yes, those lines are at the top. They are the only ones in the .htaccess file. I do not understand why it isn't working.

Comment: Put a tetxt file test.txt at domain root. Try that U can see it by domain.com/test.txt. Then change to RewriteRule ^page$ http://domain.com/test.txt [L,R=301] and try url sub.domain.com/page and shopname.bigcartel.com/page. What U see?

Comment: I have uploaded and can see the test.txt file. I have added the lines as you have said - but still it has no effect. I have looked at the main domain.com .htaccess and it has the following lines "Redirect 301 /uncategorized/page http://www.domain.com/contact
" and this works. I tried the same format in my subdomain.com root but still no change. What else can I try. I do not understand why the subdomain is ignoring the .htaccess. Thanks.

Comment: You upload text file and change line in .htaccess. What do you see when asking sub.domain.com/page ? White screen, error?..

Comment: I see the normal sub.domain.com/page page. There is no change.

Comment: Read here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride May be, it will help : if in root .htacess there is smthg as <Directory /bla/blabla/catalog_with_last_htaccess/*> AllowOverride None Option None </Directory>, it forbids .htaccess using